# Reverse every other word in string, keep punctuation Swift

Tags: string, substring, swift4, reverse, xcode9

So I got stuck on a coding challenge that I almost knew the answer too. And I think I have to use the subString call in Swift 4 to get it 100%. I want to reverse every OTHER word in a string, but ignore or keep the punctuation in its original place( index ).

```
var sample = "lets start. And not worry about proper sentences."

func reverseString(inputString: String) -> String {
    let oldSentence = sample.components(separatedBy: " ")
    var newSentence = ""
    for index in 0...oldSentence.count - 1 {
        let word = oldSentence[index]
        if newSentence != "" {
            newSentence += " "
        }
        if index % 2 == 1 {
            let reverseWord = String(word.reversed())
            newSentence += reverseWord
        } else {
            newSentence += word
        }
    }
    return newSentence
}

reverseString(inputString: sample)
```

And this would be the expected output.

```
"lets trats. And ton worry tuoba proper secnetnes."
```

Notice the punctuation is not reversed.

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `components(separatedBy: )` to split a string in words. See [this article](https://medium.com/@sorenlind/three-ways-to-enumerate-the-words-in-a-string-using-swift-7da5504f0062) for the reason. Use `enumerateSubstrings` and pass in the appropriate option:

```
func reverseString(inputString: String) -> String {
    var index = 1
    var newSentence = inputString
    inputString.enumerateSubstrings(in: inputString.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { substr, range, _, stop in
        guard let substr = substr else { return }
        if index % 2 == 0 {
            newSentence = newSentence.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: String(substr.reversed()))
        }
        index += 1
    }
    return newSentence
}

print(reverseString(inputString: "lets start. And not worry about proper sentences."))
// lets trats. And ton worry tuoba proper secnetnes.

print(reverseString(inputString: "I think, therefore I'm"))
// I kniht, therefore m'I
```

Comment: I had no idea! Thank you!

Comment: This solution seems to work perfectly, but only when you're not changing the overall length of the string you're iterating over. Here, reversing doesn't change that. But, if you want to replace every word with a longer word, this won't work. The original ranges of words in `inputString` won't change, even if you mutate `inputString`. Just a heads up!